# Good way to pass a reference to a ViewModel in an activity android

Tags: android, pass-by-reference, android-viewmodel

I have a `ViewModel` that inherits from a base class and I would like to have a corresponding `Activity` also inherit from a base class. The activity would call the same method of the derived `ViewModel` each time.  So it would be something like this:

**BaseViewModel:**

```
abstract class BaseViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    protected val context = getApplication<Application>().applicationContext

    protected var speechManager: SpeechRecognizerManager? = null

    var _actionToTake : MutableLiveData<AnalyseVoiceResults.Actions> = MutableLiveData()
    var actionToTake : LiveData<AnalyseVoiceResults.Actions> = _actionToTake

    open fun stopListening() {
        if (speechManager != null) {
        speechManager?.destroy()
        speechManager = null
    }

    open fun startListening() {
        val isListening = speechManager?.ismIsListening() ?: false
        if (speechManager == null) {
           SetSpeechListener()
        } else if (!isListening) {
           speechManager?.destroy()
           SetSpeechListener()
        }

    }
}
```

**BaseActivity**

```
class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var baseViewModel: BaseViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    fun goback() {
        super.onBackPressed()
        baseViewModel.stopListening()
        finish()
    }

    fun startListening() { 
        baseViewModel.startListening()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        baseViewModel.stopListening()
    }
}
```

**Derived Activity:**

```
class DerivedActivity : BaseActivity() {

    private val nextActivityViewModel: NextActivityViewModel by inject()
                                    ///^^inherits from BaseViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


        /*** pass reference ***/
        baseViewModel = nexActivityViewModel

        nextActivityViewModel.actionToTake.observe(this, object : Observer<AnalyseVoiceResults.Actions?> {
            override fun onChanged(t: AnalyseVoiceResults.Actions?) {
                if (t?.equals(AnalyseVoiceResults.Actions.GO_BACK) ?: false) {
                    goback()
                }
            }
         })

        startListening()
    }
}
```

Will this cause memory leaks to have two instances of a view model for this activity?  Is there a better way to do this? I don't want to keep repeating the same code for all my activities.  (I would also have the same question if I was doing this with one base fragment).

Comment: Why do you think there are 2 instances of ViewModel for your activity? You are only creating one ViewModel, and that is being referenced by two variables.

Comment: @Jaguar so is this a good approach?  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Definitely not a good approach, consider using dependency injection instead of sharing this with inheritance through some "BaseActivity" and "BaseViewModel". Honestly you probably don't even need `ViewModel` in this case, which is why it is so awkward to add it at all.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I am using koin for DI, I need it, this class was just an example of what I am doing, I need a ViewModel most definitely.

Comment: Koin should be returning a ViewModel instance via `by viewModel` and not `by inject`. MutableLiveData should not be used to send one-off actions. `ismIsListening` should just be `isListening`. And I still don't see why you need ViewModel here, especially considering that it's unclear what Activity lifecycle methods you are actually using to make `startListening/stopListening` work. Consider providing a more complete example to know what you're trying to solve.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce How should the viewmodel tell the Ui TO refresh itself?

Comment: For one-off events such as triggering navigation, you can either use the trick called `SingleLiveEvent` or the `LiveData<Event<T>>` wrapper, but you definitely shouldn't use a `MutableLiveData` directly.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I'm not.  I'm observing LiveData.

Comment: I am aware,  but you should use SingleLiveEvent (which extends MutableLiveData) to forward one-off events. See https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make this var baseViewModel: BaseViewModel an abstract variable where all the children class must override it.  So, when you call the startListening and stopListening, these methods will be called from children implementation.

**Edit:**

Make the BaseActivity an abstract class and the baseViewModel as an abstract variable

```
abstract class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private abstract var baseViewModel: BaseViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    fun goback() {
        super.onBackPressed()
        baseViewModel.stopListening()
        finish()
    }

    fun startListening() { 
        baseViewModel.startListening()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        baseViewModel.stopListening()
    }
}
```

So, your DerivedActivity must override the baseViewModel, and every call on father's class will trigger the child

```
class DerivedActivity : BaseActivity() {

    override val baseViewModel: NextActivityViewModel by inject()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

> Will this cause memory leaks to have two instances of a view model for
>   this activity?

No, there are no memory leaks with this approach. Nor do you have 2 instances of the ViewModel for the same activity. It's a single instance of ViewModel which is being referenced with different variables in BaseActivity and BaseViewModel.

> Is there a better way to do this?

The first issue I see is that you have Android specific code in the ViewModels, which is not considered a good practice. You should move the speech manager code to the base activity itself, and ViewModel should only hold the "state" data that you want to retain on orientation changes. This will ensure all the Speech Management methods (create, resume, destroy) will be in the base activity. Concrete activity will only have observers if the state changes.

If you are following any architecture pattern (like MVP), once you move the Speech Manager code out to activity, it would become obvious to move this further out to the Presenter.

**EDIT**: I have not used the MVVM pattern in production, but this is a light variant of what you may want:

The basic idea is to move Speech management code in a lifecycle-aware component. All UI code in view/activity and business logic / non-android state in viewmodel. I don't see a point in having base activity or viewmodel based on the requirements you have shared so far.

```
/**
 * All the speech related code is encapsulated here, so any new activity/fragment can use it by registering it's lifecycle
 */

class SpeechManager(private val context: Context): LifecycleObserver {

    val TAG = "SpeechManager"

    private var speechRecognizer: SpeechRecognizer? = null

    fun registerWithLifecycle(lifecycle: Lifecycle) {
        Log.e(TAG, "registerWithLifecycle")
        lifecycle.addObserver(this)
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    fun start() {
        Log.e(TAG, "start")
        speechRecognizer = (speechRecognizer ?: SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(context)).apply {

//            setRecognitionListener(object : RecognitionListener {
//                //implement methods
//            })
        }
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    fun stop() {
        Log.e(TAG, "stop")
        speechRecognizer?.run {
            stopListening()
            destroy()
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
class SpeechViewModel: ViewModel() {

    val TAG = "SpeechViewModel"

    //List all your "data/state" that needs to be restores across activity restarts
    private val actions: MutableLiveData<Actions> = MutableLiveData<Actions>().apply { value = Actions.ActionA }

    //Public API for getting observables and all use-cases
    fun getActions() = actions
    fun doActionA(){
        //validations, biz logic
        Log.e(TAG, "doActionA")
        actions.value = Actions.ActionA
    }
    fun doActionB(){
        Log.e(TAG, "doActionB")
        actions.value = Actions.ActionB
    }
}

sealed class Actions{
    object ActionA: Actions()
    object ActionB: Actions()
}
```

Activity/View:

```
class SpeechActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_speech)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        initSpeechManager()
    }

    private lateinit var speechManager: SpeechManager
    private lateinit var speechViewModel: SpeechViewModel

    /**
     * Register lifecycle aware components and start observing state changes from ViewModel.
     * All UI related code should ideally be here (or your view equivalent in MVVM)
     */
    private fun initSpeechManager() {
        speechManager = SpeechManager(this).apply {registerWithLifecycle(lifecycle)}
        speechViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SpeechViewModel::class.java).apply {
            getActions().observe(this@SpeechActivity, Observer<Actions>{
                when(it){
                    is Actions.ActionA -> {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Perform ActionA")
                        speechManager.start()
                    }
                    is Actions.ActionB -> {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Perform ActionB")
                        speechManager.stop()
                        super.onBackPressed()
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the activity just be "dumb" and not have any kind of business logic?

Comment: I am using MVVM architecture.

Comment: @KristyWelsh I have shared a simple implementation based on my understanding of MVVM and speech manager. One reason I avoid MVVM because the role of VM is confusing, and this reflects in my code.

Comment: I get you, most devs I know have migrated to MVVM. Anyway, do you see any problems with the code/design I shared? I don't think you need base activity/viewmodel for you speech related code - of course you should have those base classes for other features.

Comment: the only problem I see is putting business logic in the activity.  That's why I have placed all the business logic into the ViewModel.  I could further break out the business logic into a use case, though.